# Changing character_set_client , character_set_connection and character_set_results only on one database schema

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to set below variables only to my database instance? without affecting/changing any other databases that is on the same server?

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4'
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4'
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4'
```

Comment: Noway. Imagine that the database in interest is `db1`, in some connection default database is `db2`, and client executes `... FROM db1.table1 JOIN db3.table3 ...` - what parameters do you want to be applied? If some client/application needs in specific character set settings it must set according session variables values during connecting.

Comment: aaaah that perfectly makes sense. The reason I ask was because everytime I logged in to my db server , I need to set those variables just so the Japanese characters will show fine in he query result instead of a question mark.

Comment: See carefully your connection settings/commands. Most libraries contains a property which stores command(s) which are executed during the connection process - put according SET statements into this property.

Comment: Thanks @Akina, please put this as answer I'll accept it

Comment: I think the best option is when you, not me, add self-answer. With an exact indication of the access library/framework used and the specific commands that you used to solve the problem.